# How to integrate billdesk payment gateway in my php website so that i can make transactions from indian bank

Tags: php

I want to integrate billdesk payment gateway in my php website. So that i can make transactions from indian banks. I am new to this so please help me out. If it is possible than send me the link of any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the bank itself would be expected to provide such tutorials. If you can't find any on their site, then it's unlikely that you'll find them elsewhere unless it's a bank that's already very widely used for online transaction processing. Call them and ask them what help they can provide. Banks I've worked with have always been very happy to help.

Rather than just integrating into your website, it can be helpful to use an existing, popular shopping cart system e.g. [Ubercart](http://www.ubercart.org/), which will have a lot of the code you need already in place and will have examples of where similar plugins has been done with other banks, e.g. [here](http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_alpha_deltapay).